# Can't checkout of branch in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

There aren't any changes to commit in the current branch, but when I try to checkout to another branch Xcode prompts me to stash changes, then gives...

'The working copy has conflicting, uncommitted changes. Commit or discard the changes and try again. '

Looking through SO threads my guess is this is to do with changes on a different branch but I can't see how to investigate this without checking out of the current branch.

Comment: What happens when you do `git status` from the command line?

Comment: @jnpdx "Your branch is up to date with ...." "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: And what happens if you try to switch to another branch from the command line?

Comment: If I checkout through the command line it says 'Switched to branch <the correct branch>'... but this doesn't have any effect in Xcode. I tried restarting Xcode but still get the same 'Working copy has conflicting....' message when trying to checkout

Comment: OK, so there is no problem with Git, just with XCode.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (presumably because of a change in another branch), Xcode had flagged one of the files in the current branch 'C' as opposed to 'M'...

Using this link:

https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

C..."The contents (as opposed to the properties) of the item conflict with updates received from the repository."

versus...

M..."Item has been modified."

Going into the file flagged 'C' in the commit window in Xcode Source Control and manually setting each change in this file to 'commit' solved this issue.